# Partial directory list in linux

Tags: linux, shell

If I have a directory containing hundreds of files, using `ls`, `ls-l`, or `dir` gives me a list that's too long for the command terminal screen, so I'm unable to see most of the files in the directory.

I recall there being some argument for `ls` that allows one to scroll through the list in short increments, but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 10):

One option is to pipe the output to `less` or `more`

```
ls | less
```

or

```
ls | more
```

Comment: You can make a function of this so you can pass various ls options: `ll() { ls "$@" | less; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
ls -1 | less
```

Comment: `ls` will automatically print a single column when it's stdout is a pipe, so you don't need the `-1`

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to redirect the output of `ls` into a temporary file and then view that file with any editor of your choice - that way you can do searches etc. as well:

```
ls > res.tmp
vim res.tmp
emacs res.tmp
gedit res.tmp
grep "pattern" res.tmp
```

Comment: `ls > tes.tmp && wine word.exe res.tmp` (just kidding)